A dystopian place where it was forbidden to be fat
I remember very little about this movie. It was like an dystopian place where it was forbidden to be fat. And people had to hide in the jungle or something like that. Also, in one scene one guy is about to kill himself with a gun when he sees people whom were hidden and decide do not do it.
I have no further details about the movie. This is all I remember. I do not know the language, but I suppose it was American. I probably heard about/watched the movie 15 years ago, which doesn't mean the movie was released 15 years ago. All I remember is the plot. Actually, I don't remember if I ever watched this movie or if a cousin told me about it. I was really young at the time.

Welcome to the site,this question doesn't give much information to go on.  Is there anything else you can add to the answer?  What language was the movie in? was it an American movie?  What's the approximate age of the movie?  When were you 'really young'?

I have no further details about the movie. This is all I remember. I do not know the language, but I suppose it was american. I probably heard about/watched the movie 15 years ago, which doesn't mean the movie was released 15 years ago.
All I remember is the plot..

OK, thanks for responding, at least. You're pretty much describing the journey of Abraham Benrubi's heavy-set character in Tempting Fate in a parallel universe. See this answer.

@EdelyGomes: It's best indeed if you have a better time window the for approximative year of release, but a least, saying that you watched it 15 years ago, we can exclude movies past 2005 (at least, which is quite a lot a movie indeed). It's just, that the more details you gave, the more chances you have to find it.

@Larme I understand what you say. The point is: I don't remember. Really.

@EdelyGomes Have you looked at Tempting Fate yet? This is exactly what happens there (a guy finds himself in a world that casts out heavy-set people and is sent to a cabin, where he almost kills himself with a gun but stops when all the people like him emerge from their hiding in the woods). The timeline fits too (it's from 17 years ago). The actor was Abraham Benrubi and the film is currently available on Youtube here.

@Walt Wow! Thanks. I think this is it! Are you going to add the answer? So I can accept it.

De nada. ;) If this is the one, let me know and I'll simply mark it as a duplicate.

@Walt, I watched the movie and is Tempting Fate indeed. Thanks!

@EdelyGomes the movie is TEMPTING FATE, 1998

Logan's Run?  Forbidden to be old instead of fat.  The scenes of Washington D.C. was essentially a jungle.

I think it makes sense. I am going to give a try and watch this movie and see if matchs.
